# How Can I replace "NaN" with a space in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I need to replace "NaN" with a space in an array

```
var result = [1, 2, 3, NaN]
console.log(result)
```

I would like the output to be [1, 2, 3, " "]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can simply do this:

```
result.map(value => isNaN(value) ? ' ' : value);
```

Comment: Recommended to use `Number.isNaN`, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/isNaN

Comment: Even if the approach is correct, please note that you are replacing by an `empty string`, while the OP wanted a `space` :)

Answer (score 2):

Use `isNaN()` for checking in `forEach`

```js
var result = [1, 2, 3, NaN]
arr=[];
result.forEach((e)=>!isNaN(e)?arr.push(e):arr.push(''))
console.log(arr)
```

Using map

```js
var result = [1, 2, 3, NaN];
console.log(result.map((e)=>isNaN(e)?"":e))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use map():

```js
var result = [0, 1, 2, 3, NaN]
result = result.map(e=>isNaN(e)?' ':e)
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `isNaN()` to find `NaN` elements.

```
var result = [1, 2, 3, NaN];

for (var i in result)
    if (isNaN(result[i]))
        result[i] = "";

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Sure, but `map` will be much cleaner.

Comment: @Scott Sauyet  Yes, but I'm not very sure if he can use `map`.

Answer (score -1):

You can use [`findIndex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex). See example below:

```js
var result = [1, 2, 3, NaN];
var i = result.findIndex(Number.isNaN);
result[i] = " ";
console.log(result);
```

Comment: You should probably test something like this before you post.  `NaN` is a very odd value.

Comment: @ScottSauyet. You're right. I've updated my answer to use `findIndex` instead of `indexOf`

Comment: This only works if there is one NaN, not if there are multiples.

Comment: `findIndex` is only part of it.  Probably more relevant is the change from an equality test to `Number.isNaN`.  But see some of the other answers for perhaps simpler techniques.